# Relation between size of address bus and memory size; memory Segmentation in 8086

Tags: cpu, cpu-registers, processor, microprocessors, memory-segmentation

My question is related to memory segmentation in 8086. I learnt that,

> 8086 has a 20 bit address bus. And so it can address 2^20 different addresses. Which means it has an memory size of 2^20, i.e, 1MB.

I have a few doubts:

1. What I understand from the fact that 8086 has a 20 bit address bus is that it could have 2^20 different combinations of 0s and 1s, each of which represents one physical address. What I don't understand is that how does 2^20 different address locations mean 1 MB of addressable memory? How is total number of different addresses locations  related to memory size (in Megabytes)?
2. Also, correct me if I'm wrong, the 16 bit segment registers in 8086 hold the starting address of the different segments in the memory (Code, Stack, Data, Extra).My question is, aren't the addresses in memory of 20 bits? Then how can the 16 bit register hold 20 bit addresses? If it contains the upper 16 bit of the 20 bit address, how does the processor make out to which exact address location it has to point?

*P.S: I am a beginner is micro-processors and total reliant on self study, so kindly excuse if my questions seem a bit silly.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. For this question, its important to remember there is a different between the number of possible memory addresses and the amount of actual memory (RAM) installed in the system. For the 8086, memory addresses are 20-bits long as you note, so that means there are 2^20 possible memory addresses (which is exactly 1 MiB in size since 1 MiB is 1024 or 2^10 KiB and 1 KiB is 1024 or 2^10 Bytes). This does NOT mean the system has 1 MiB worth of RAM necessarily, it very likely has less but the most addresses the 8086 could possibly address is 1 MiB; so if nothing but RAM was in the address space, the most RAM it could possibly have is 1 MiB. Frequently, you might have gaps in the address space not filled with anything, some of the address space is used for ROM or other peripherals. So, that size of the address space is 1 MiB but that does not mean there is 1 MiB of RAM/memory in the system.
2. Correct, the segment registers are all 16-bits for the 8086. A memory address is created by combining the appropriate segment register with the argument (the argument being the result of whatever the addressing mode being used by the instruction) by adding the argument to the segment register's value shifted by 4 bits. So, if for example the `ss` is `0x1111`, `sp` is at `0x2222` and you preform a `push ax` instruction, the 20-bit address to which the value is pushed is `(ss << 4) + sp` or `0x11110 + 0x02222 = 0x13332`. More information can be found on Wikipedia under the Real Mode section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation